# PHP CLI very different process title on Debian 32 vs Ubuntu 64

Tags: ubuntu, debian, php, ps

I have two servers **Debian Squeeze 32** and **Ubuntu 11.10 Server 64**. The same script with the same command behaves very different.

Script test.php:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { echo $i, "\n"; sleep(1); }
```

Command:

```
php -q test.php &
ps | grep php
```

Debain: I see numbers being printed and process title is `php -q test.php` as expected. `pidof "php -q test.php"` works fine.

Ubuntu: No numbers; process title is `php`. `pidof "php -q test.php"` does not work and I can't use `pidof php`.

What's wrong with Ubuntu?

**Update** WOW! `pgrep -f "php -q test.php"` works well while `pidof "php -q test.php"` doesn't.

**Update 2** I'm not sure if this may apply, but under Debian I'm working in a regular console, while Ubuntu is being accessed by SSH.

Comment: may be worth trying to givie the full command line to php

Comment: @Dagon `/usr/bin/php -q test.php &` then `ps | grep php` produces absolutely the same. `php` is the title and `pidof` behaves the same.

Comment: Works for me on the same Ubuntu version, 64-bit.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 and Debian Squeeze 32 (VirtualBox).

Comment: I also tried to ssh connect from the Squeeze machine to the Ubuntu machine. The problem still exists. So I assume it is not a terminal issue

Comment: What does 'process title is' mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with missing output is known and caused by the readline extension.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php) :

> When readline is enabled, php switches the terminal mode to accept line-buffered input. 
>   This means that the proper way to use the cli when you pipe to an interactive command is to explicitly specify that php is not using the terminal for input:

```
php somescript.php < /dev/null | less
```

The difference between Debian and Ubuntu is that in Ubuntu's PHP package readline is enabled  and in Debians package it is disabled.

So the solution to your problem - although your are not using a pipe - is:

```
php -q test.php < /dev/null &
```

If you redirect stdin to `/dev/null` the numbers will be printed on terminal as expected.

You may also read this [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/907905)